# Postgresql - relation doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql script which selects all information about tables and views for specific database. I'm trying to add a additional column which will display comment associated with a table or a view.
But I'm getting an error SQL state: 42P01, ERROR: relation "xxx" does not exist.

```
select tbl.*, (select obj_description(tbl.table_name::regclass::oid, 'pg_class')) as DESCRIPTION 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES tbl 
where tbl.table_schema <> 'pg_catalog' and tbl.table_schema <> 'information_schema' 
order by tbl.table_schema, tbl.table_name
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In few words: `obj_description((tbl.table_schema || '.' || tbl.table_name)::regclass` - use fully qualified names, including the schema name.

Comment: @Abelisto Thanks, it works.

Comment: Actually the right answer is a combination of my comment and the answer of @LaurenzAlbe. Also you can avoid subquery in the `select` clause so it could be: `select tbl.*, obj_description(format('%I.%I',tbl.table_schema, tbl.table_name)::regclass, 'pg_class') as DESCRIPTION from ...` Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This incorporates Abelisto's comments above.

You should use

```
obj_description(
   (quote_ident(tbl.table_name) || '.' || quote_ident(tbl.table_name))::regclass::oid,
   'pg_class'
)
```

instead of

```
(select obj_description(tbl.table_name::regclass::oid, 'pg_class'))
```

I guess that some of your table names are not all lower case.